# In DAML, how to get ContractId in a choice

Tags: daml

In DAML, can I save a contractId of B in contract A? I tried the followings but creating contract returns an update and I cannot save that update anywhere or even access to its data.

```
template OneContract
  with
    someParty : Party
    someText : Text
    someNumber : Int  
  where
    signatory someParty



template Main
  with
    anyone :  Party
    cid : ContractId OneContract
  where
    signatory anyone

    controller anyone can
      nonconsuming CreateOneContracts : ()
        with 
          p : Party
          int : Int
        do
-- cid is not bind to cid in the contract
          cid <- create OneContract with someParty = p, someText = "same", 
someNumber = int
-- let won't work since create returns an update 
          let x = create OneContract with someParty = p, someText = "same", 
someNumber = int
          pure()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea with `cid <- ...`, but that will create a new local variable `cid` with the contract id in it. All data in DAML is immutable, which means you can't write into `this.cid`. You have to archive the contract and recreate it to change the data stored on it:

```
template Main
  with
    anyone :  Party
    cid : ContractId OneContract
  where
    signatory anyone

    controller anyone can
      CreateOneContracts : ContractId Main
        with 
          p : Party
          int : Int
        do
          newCid <- create OneContract with someParty = p, someText = "same", someNumber = int
          create this with cid = newCid
```

Note that this will only work with `anyone == p`, though. `p`'s authority is needed to create a `OneContract with someParty = p`, and the only authority available in the context of the `CreateOneContracts` choice is that of `anyone`.

Comment: it works. Thanks a lot. One more question, can this be done in one statement? e.g. without using newCid?